# How to customize width table in python-docx

Tags: python-3.x, python-docx

I want to make a table in Document Word using `python-docx` but the width of the table is always max to the ruler. How can I customize this?

My code:

```
def table_columns(text, my_rows):
    
    row = table.rows[0].cells
    paragraph = row[my_rows].add_paragraph()
    get_paragraph = paragraph.add_run(text)
    paragraph.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.CENTER
    get_paragraph.bold = True
    font = get_paragraph.font
    font.size= Pt(10)

table = doc.add_table(rows = 1, cols = 5, style = 'Table Grid')

columns_width = {
    0: 2,
    1: 35,
    2: 35,
    3: 42,
    4: 170
}
for column_idx in range(len(table.columns)):
    table.cell(0, column_idx).width = Cm(columns_width[column_idx])

for rows_idx in range(len(table.rows)):
    table.rows[rows_idx].height = Cm(1.25)

columns_names = {
    0: 'NO',
    1: 'VALUE1',
    2: 'VALUE2',
    3: 'VALUE3',
    4: 'VALUE4'
}
for column_idx in range(len(table.columns)):
    table_columns(columns_names[column_idx], column_idx)
```

I also change the `columns_width` but give the same result.

Here are the results and what I want to make to:
[image: table]

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Cell width is what matters here. You are using:

```
columns_width = {
    0: 2,
    1: 35,
    2: 35,
    3: 42,
    4: 170
}
table.cell(0, column_idx).width = Cm(columns_width[column_idx])
```

to set the cell widths, which is fine, but you are using large Cm() (centimeter) lengths to do it. For example, 170 cm is 1.7 meters.

If you use Pt() instead or possibly Mm() I think you'll get better results.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, Scanny. I used Pt() or Mm() but still got the same result, stucking to the ruler.

Comment: Isn't the issue here that @PythonBeginner is setting position coordinatees rather than widths? Isn't each width meant to be independently measured from zero?

Comment: @Alan Doesn't look like that to me, but I do notice he's setting the column width, which I don't believe does anything. For whatever reason you need to set the width of each cell in the column to actually affect layout width, as I recall. So if you're having the same problem you might try that.

Comment: For me the answer was to set table.autowidth = False